# Правильно ли оформлена цитата?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

```
"Ничто не причина" – пишет Лев Николаевич – "Все это только совпадение..."
```

Answer (score 7):

> «Ничто не причина, — пишет Лев Николаевич. — Всё это только совпадение…»

Rosenthal et al., *Справочник по правописанию…*, §121:

> 1. Если авторские слова стоят внутри прямой речи, выделяемой кавычками, то последние ставятся только в начале и в конце прямой речи и не ставятся между прямой речью и авторскими словами, например: *«Я могу читать, — первый опять заговорил Петрусь, — и скоро выучусь писать пером»* (Короленко).
> 2. Если на месте разрыва прямой речи должна была стоять точка, то перед авторскими словами ставятся запятая и тире, а после них – точка и тире; вторая часть прямой речи начинается с прописной буквы. Например: *«Их распустили до приговора, — сказал дворник. — Объявят завтра, в девять вечера»* (Трифонов).

Ibid, §124:

> 1. Цитаты заключаются в кавычки. Если цитата оформляется как прямая речь, т.е. сопровождается словами автора, приводящего её, то применяются соответствующие правила пунктуации (см. §119–122).
>    …
>    *«Мне кажется, что стиль перевода не будет нарушен, — пишет Корней Чуковский, — если мы в меру и с тактом будем в своем переводе передавать иностранные пословицы и поговорки русскими, особенно в тех случаях, когда буквальный перевод неуклюж и многословен».*

Comment: По сути дела это и есть прямая речь,  где автор текста представляет оригинал цитаты как речь персонажа-автора цитаты, но Розенталь  сделал правильно, описав этот случай отдельно чтобы избежать  сомнений.

Comment: @Swift - Поскольку эта цитата из художественного произведения, «Война и мир», то там _вообще все_ слова, даже «слова от автора» являются не прямой речью реального Льва Толстого, а словами одного из персонажей этой книги, Рассказчика. Это же _fiction_, там всё происходит в одном из возможных миров, но уж никак не в реальном, и, естественно, «слова от автора» там тоже говорит не реальный, а один из возможных Львов Толстых. Да, Розенталь действительно сделал правильно, но не для того, чтобы «избежать сомнений», а чтобы описать все _реальные_ случаи, потому что он-то написал именно _non-fiction_.

Comment: @Yellow Sky И в  non-fiction есть персонажи, т.е. реальные люди о которых идет речь.Если кто-то что-то пишет  и это оформляется как прямая речь, это все равно прямая речь. Существует два подхода - описание всех  возможных случаев и описание  формальных правил. Розенталь использовал первый. Первый удобен людям, так как он не требует ползания по тексту параграфов и  решения силлогизмов на основании данных формулировок, второй удобен для  описания стандартов (и машинной реализации анализа в итоге).Для русского языка более удобен первый, хотя официальные власти сейчас стремятся использовать второй

Comment: @Swift - Но согласитесь, что ведь, скажем, я сейчас могу переписать в другой блог ваш тутошний предыдущий комментарий и подписаться вашим именем, а про меня потом напишут художественную книжку, в которой будет говориться, что я, Swift, написал то-то и там-то (но я-то Yellow Sky и написал это не я и не в том другом блоге) и что, это будет прямой речью? Так же и в «Войне и мире» вымышленный персонаж с именем Наполеон может слово-в-слово повторить реальную речь реального Наполеона Бонапарта, но это никак прямой речью самого императора Франции не будет, ибо это всё fiction. Это я просто к слову.

Comment: Yellow Sky Вообще это допустимо (хотя и может быть фактологически неверно).Зависит от стиля представления и цели повествования, взгляните на то как писали критики художественной литературы. Тут и Чичикова появляется прямая речь, если критик пишет о нем как о (гипотетически существующем) человеке